# join consecutive lines with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python output file with more than 30 columns, The output file format is that each line is separated to multiple lines by a backslash. Here is the example of how two lines separated in 6 lines: (Lets say file name is : EPA.csv)

```
1 U.S Air Quality\

1 is being monitored\

1 by EPA.

2 And EPA conducts extensive\

2 research on \

2 the ambient air quality.
```

I want to join the consecutive lines with backslash and keep only one line number for each line. For example I want the output like following:

```
1 U.S. Air Quality is being monitored by EPA.

2 And EPA conducts extensive research on the ambient air quality.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: We cannot help you unless you post what ever you've tried so far.

Comment: Hello Iqbal! Try to make a clear question. Otherwise, other people with the same problem will not be able to reuse (find) it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> t = """1 U.S Air Quality\\
... 1 is being monitored\\
... 1 by EPA.
... 2 And EPA conducts extensive\\
... 2 research on \\
... 2 the ambient air quality."""
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in t.split('\n'):
...  d[i.split(' ')[0]] = i[2:]
>>> d
{'1': 'U.S Air Quality1 is being monitored1 by EPA.', '2': 'And EPA conducts extensive2 research on 2 the ambient air quality.'}
>>> for e in d:
...  print(e, d[e].rstrip('\\'))
... 
1 U.S Air Quality1 is being monitored1 by EPA.
2 And EPA conducts extensive2 research on 2 the ambient air quality.
```

Comment: Hi @Yuri, Thanks for the help. The output of your code contains 1 & 2 in the sentences. For example here " 1 U.S Air Quality1 is being monitored1 by EPA." you can see 1 after Quality and monitored words. But I am looking to keep only first 1 at line starting point i.e. "1 U.S Air Quality is being monitored by EPA."

Comment: @Iqbal, Yuri gave you a pretty good answer. Don't you think you can take his answer from here and make it work? If you do not know how to detect and remove characters in a string, you may want to look into the replace() function or into the regex module.